# InvalidSchema No connection adapters were found for , error in django

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, python-requests, robobrowser

I'm experimenting with http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/readme.html, a new python library based on the beautiful soup  and requests ibraries. I'm currently using it to open a series of pages and saving the response into a list for later parsing. The list in my debugger looks like:

```
pages =   [<Response [200]>, <Response [200]> ....]
```

I generated this list by having the robobrowser object loop through some pages and save the responses:

```
while pageRight:
    browser.follow_link(pageright[0])
    browser
    page = browser.response
    pages.append(page)
    pageRight= browser.select(".pageright")
```

This above part seems to be working fine, however when I try:

```
ag = "myagent"
browser = RoboBrowser(user_agent=ag)

for page in pages:
    browser.open(page.content)
    for listing in browser.select('.listingInfo'): #a list
        pl = getParsedListing(listing)
        listings.append(pl)
```

in my django index file, I'm getting the error:

```
InvalidSchema at /index/

No connection adapters were found for..
```

traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\envs\r1\masslist\ml1\views.py" in index
  29.         Sites = getSitesInArea(Area)
File "C:\envs\r1\masslist\ml1\views.py" in getSitesInArea
  91.         browser.open(page.content)
File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\browser.py" in open
  200.             verify=verify if verify is not None else self.verify,
File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py" in get
  468.         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py" in request
  456.         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py" in send
  553.         adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py" in get_adapter
  608.         raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)    

Exception Type: InvalidSchema at /index/
Exception Value: No connection adapters were found for '
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: How are you generating the requests? You might have to include the protocol in the requests. `http://www.google.com`

Comment: I have made some edits. - Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `pages` is a list of Response objects, and you're calling `browser.open` on the `content` attribute of each response. But the `open` method takes a URL, not the contents of a response. If you're looking to open each page in your `pages` list, try this:

```
for page in pages:
    browser.open(page.url)
    ...
```

I believe that will work, but it's going to be inefficient, since it means visiting each page in your list twice (once in your `while pageRight` loop, and again in your `for page in pages` loop). To make this more efficient, you might combine both loops into one:

```
while pageRight:
    for listing in browser.select('.listingInfo'):
        pl = getParsedListing(listing)
        listings.append(pl)
    browser.follow_link(pageright[0])
    pageRight = browser.select(".pageright")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Robobrowser (it seems). It is probably looking for `<a href="...">Link Name</a>` and just taking what is in the `"..."` part. Based on the relevant RFCs (specifically 3986) this can be either `//example.com/path/to/resource` or `http://example.com/path/to/resource` or just `/path/to/resource`. What you're seeing is that it found something with a path segment only `/index/` and it assumes it can just use it. What robobrowser should be doing (which is what *browsers* do) is determining what the full URI is based off of Section 5 of RFC 3986. Fortunately for them, there will be a library very soon that will be capable of doing this for them.

Comment: It's not finished but the library is unoriginally titled rfc3986. It's on PyPI.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for it.